# automated android config

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I'm looking for a way to automate the configuration of Android devices en masse. Particularly Samsung Galaxy Tabs. Poking around, I've found software like http://www.ranorex.com/mobile-automation-testing/android-test-automation.html that can automate the testing/config of a single app that the software itself installs. It's all graphical, so you just start recording, and the software records all the touches and button presses. You can play this back on any devices connected to your WiFi network.

What I'm trying to do is similar to that software, but can be used outside of a single app, system modifications. Say I want to ensure that 1000 devices are all configured similarly, backlight settings, WiFi, GPS, etc.. Mainly the stuff that MDM cannot push OTA. None of the apps on the Play Store seem to do what I'm needing (all very consumer, single device focused)

It looks like monkeyrunner could possibly work, but we don't have any programmers with Python knowledge in-house.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MonkeyRunner is really your only option as Robotium can only interact with one app at a time.

If none of your programmers have python experience then ChimpChat may be of use. ChimpChat should let you do the same things as monkey runner, but you can program it in java. An introduction to ChimpChat can be found [here](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2011/11/android-using-monkey-from-java.html).

Comment: I think that should definitely help us out. I'll pass that information along and see how it'll work. Thank you for the link!

Comment: No problem. If you could click on the check mark next to the answer in order to accept it I would be appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/)? This is an open source black box testing framework for Android. I've used it successfully to automate the build verification testing of our mobile applications. You can use Java to implement the code.

I didn't use monkeyrunner as it seems you can only identify elements by position on the screen, which can obviously change on screens with different resolutions.

Robotium allows you to use ID of elements. If you need to install anything on the devices, I'd suggest just using [adb](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) which comes with the Android SDK, and can be easily scripted via a batch file or from a Java program.

Comment: Doesn't look like that'll work out. But also probably means nothing will work for what we're needing. This [page](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RobotiumForPreInstalledApps) states that in order to modify system settings or any pre-installed apps it requires root. These will be devices we configure and ship out to customers, so that isn't an option.. Monkeyrunner could work, as each project will be all the exact same device type and should be configured completely identical.